# How to match image name with database record?

Tags: php

I've got the following problem:

I have some images in a folder and a sql database record.I have to fetch all images from folder and we have to match that image name with having the field in the database. If these are same then we have to rename that image with the another name. How would I do that?

```
  <?php
    $query = "Select ITCFields.ImageID,UDFields.Zoho_ID from ITCFields,UDFields where 
    ITCFields.ImageID='1234899'";
    $resa = odbc_exec($conn,$query);
    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>ZohoID</th>
    <th>Image</th>
    <th>Full_Name</th>
    </tr>";
    while( $row = odbc_fetch_array($resa) ) {
        echo "<tr>";
        $zoho_id=$row['Zoho_ID'];
        $image_id=$row['ImageID'];
        echo "<td>" .$zoho_id."</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$image_id."</td>";
        $full_name=$zoho_id.'_'.$image_id.'.jpg';
        echo "<td>" .$full_name."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
            }
    odbc_close($conn);

    ?>
<?php
define("BASE_IMAGE_PATH","D:\\");
define("IMAGE_FOLDER_NAME","2014finalfour\\");
define("IMAGE_FOLDER_NAME_MODIFIED","modified\\");
define("IMAGE_File_Path",BASE_IMAGE_PATH.IMAGE_FOLDER_NAME);
define("IMAGE_File_Path_Modified",BASE_IMAGE_PATH.IMAGE_FOLDER_NAME.IMAGE_FOLDER_NAME_MODIFIED);
$srcdir=constant("IMAGE_File_Path");
$destdir=constant("IMAGE_File_Path_Modified");
if (!file_exists(IMAGE_File_Path_Modified)) {
    mkdir(IMAGE_File_Path_Modified, 0777, true);
}

$srcdire=opendir($srcdir);
while($readFile = readdir($srcdire))
{
    if($readFile != '.' && $readFile != '..')
    {
        if (!file_exists($readFile)) 
        {
            if(copy($srcdir . $readFile, $destdir . $readFile ))
            {
                echo "Copy file";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Canot Copy file";
            }
        }
    }
}

closedir($srcdir);

?>
<?php

$directory=constant("IMAGE_File_Path_Modified");                                
if ($dir = opendir($directory) )
{
    $images = array();
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {

        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            $images[] = $file; 

        }

    }

    closedir($dir);

}

foreach($images as $image) {

    echo $image."</br>";

}

?>
```

Please Help me to sought out it.

Answer (score 0):

Is image name very important in your code logic?

Usually the problem of having duplicate images is solved by hashing the image name to a unique name (for example with the unix date time value) when it is uploaded and using that name for all further logic. So the unique name for the name becomes the hashed name and you can still use the original name to display if required as another field in the table.

So the problem essentially becomes that of giving each image a unique name then to track if it is unique.

Below is the code of uploading the image.

```
function uploadImage($image,$path,$thumbpath)
{
    if($image!=''){
        $explode=explode('.',$_FILES[$image]['name']);
        $file=time().'.'.$explode[1];
        $file_tempname=$_FILES[$image]['tmp_name'];
        move_uploaded_file($file_tempname,$path.$file);
        createThumb($path.$file,$thumbpath.$file, 80, 80);
    }
    return $file;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all fetch all the folder images name than match with your db images name.

```
$dir = "/images/";
         $img_name = scandir($dir);
         while( $row = odbc_fetch_array($resa) ) { echo "";
           $zoho_id=$row['Zoho_ID']; 
           $image_id=$row['ImageID']; 
           echo "" .$zoho_id.""; 
           echo "" .$image_id."";
           $full_name=$zoho_id.'_'.$image_id.'.jpg';

           if(in_array($full_name,$img_name)){
               //do your chanes
           }
           echo "" .$full_name.""; 


         }
```